# How to auto-null referenced entities upon deletion of parent via a cascade type?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

for example  there are two table  branch (parent entity) and student (child entity). if branch is deleted then students in the branch will deleted in(cascade type.ALL).but I want to delete the branch then the students is related to that branch is changed to no branch for the student?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such automatic cascade option. You'd have to manually set the branch reference to `null` and remove the branch:

```java
child.setBranch(null);
entityManager.remove(branch);
```